# Invalid certificate error with Geckodriver on FF 51

Tags: java, firefox, ui-automation, geckodriver, selenium3

I am using Selenium 3 on Firefox 51.0.1 with Geckodriver release v0.14.0. I am getting an error on the browser trying to open the URL, and it says the connection is not secure (certificate error), although I checked the certificate and it is valid.

The error is this:

```
Command failed: open target="" value="https://mydomain.mysite.com/default" -> Reached error page: about:certerror?e=nssBadCert&u=https%3A//mydomain.mysite.com/default&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=mydomain.mysite.com%20uses%20an%20invalid%20security%20certificate.%0A%0AThe%20certificate%20is%20not%20trusted%20because%20the%20issuer%20certificate%20is%20unknown.%0AThe%20server%20might%20not%20be%20sending%20the%20appropriate%20intermediate%20certificates.%0AAn%20additional%20root%20certificate%20may%20need%20to%20be%20imported.%0A%0AError%20code%3A%20%3Ca%20id%3D%22errorCode%22%20title%3D%22SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER%22%3ESEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER%3C/a%3E%0A
```

I am using the following code (partial snippet below) to set the capabilities on FF, and it appears that **acceptSslCerts**​ is **not** getting set to **true**.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckoDriverLocation);

DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, 1);

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

// Set the download path in Firefox profile
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "/User/me/download");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "images/jpeg, application/pdf, application/octet-stream, application/zip, application/xml");
profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);​

profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);

desiredCapabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);

return new FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities);
```

If I put a breakpoint on the last statement above and check, it returns `((RemoteWebDriver) webDriver).getCapabilities().getCapability("acceptSslCerts")` as **false**. That is **acceptSslCerts** is **not** getting set to **true**. The detailed error message (not shown here) shows the same fact.

Could this be the reason why the error is happening? What could be done to ensure this value (**acceptSslCerts**) gets set correctly?

Note that the error does not occur with Selenium 2 on FF 47 with Firefoxdriver.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the update posted below, it is not possible to fix the above problem unless Firefox v52 is used.

https://www.hskupin.info/2017/01/23/using-selenium-and-webdriver-to-interact-with-insecure-ssl-pages-in-firefox/

Tried out with FF 52 which is still in beta. It worked!